# Why explicit template arguments are required when overriding virtual functions?

Tags: c++

Here's my problem. I got the following error if I don't put template argument explicitly in derived::getType() function.

*class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z*

But even with -std flag, it still fires error.

```
class myT {
    // full implementation
};

template<class T>
class base {
public:
    virtual my_getter_type<T>* getter() = 0;
}

class derived : public base<myT> {
public:
    my_getter_type<myT>* getter();   // this is OK, no compile error
    my_getter_type* getType();       // this is NOT OK, compile error
}
```

Comment: Class template argument deduction isn't allowed in a function return type anyway. The error message is indeed misleading.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the template argument is known already given that I put "myT" when deriving the base class? Why does the compiler require explicit template argument for getter() function? What's the potential issue it's trying to avoid?

Comment: Please post actual, complete and minimal code. There's no definition of `my_getter_type`.

Comment: @fyang29 See Pete's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it. The return type must be a type, obviously. `my_getter_type<myT>*` is a type. `my_getter_type` is a template.

`my_getter_type*` doesn't make sense either, because to form a pointer type the `*` has to follow a base type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inherent connection between the return type of a function in a base class and the return type of a function with the same name in a derived class. That is, it's perfectly legal to do this:

```
struct base {
    int f();
};

struct derived : base {
    double f();
};
```

Making `f()` virtual in the base doesn't change that.

Same thing with the return type of `getter()` in the question; the base class version returns `my_getter_type<T>`, but that does not mean that the derived version must also return `my_getter_type<T>`; again, it would be perfectly legal for the derived version of `getter()` to return `my_getter_type<T*>`, `int`, `void`, or anything else.

And, of course, `my_getter_type` is a template, not a type, so cannot be a legal return type.

Comment: Thanks. I think this explains it. By the way, I don’t think it’s possible to override a function with a different return type.

Comment: @fyang29 -- if you're overriding a virtual function there are some limited things that can be different in the return type. If the return type in the base Is a pointer or reference to some type `T`, an overriding function can return a pointer or reference to a type derived from `T`. That's referred to as a covariant return type. Other than that, as you say, the type has to be the same.